# ajax xmlHttp.readyState==4 is not executed

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

```
// JavaScript Document
var xmlHttp = createXmlHttpRequestObject();

function createXmlHttpRequestObject(){
    var xmlHttp;

    if(window.ActiveXObject){
        try{
            xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

        }
        catch(e){
            xmlHttp=false;
        }
    }
    else{
        try{
            xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

        }
        catch(e){
            xmlHttp=false;
        }
    }
    if(!xmlHttp){
        alert('cant create the object');
    }
    else{

        return xmlHttp;
    }
}
```

---

```
function process(){

    if(xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState==0){

        food=encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("userinput").value);
        xmlHttp.open("GET","foodstore.php?food="+food,true);
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=handleServerResponse;
        xmlHttp.send(null);
    }
    else{
                setTimeout(process(),1000);
    }
}
```

---

```
function handleServerResponse(){

    if(xmlHttp.readyState==4 ){
        if( xmlHttp.status==200){

            xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML;
            xmlDocumentElement =xmlResponse.documentElement;
            message=xml.DocumentElement.firstChild.data;
            document.getElementById("underinput").innerHTML=message;
            setTimeout(process(),1000);
        }
        else{

            alert('something went wrong');
        }
    }
    else{
        alert('something went wrong 2');
    }
}
```

In above code, my `xmlHttp.readyState==4` is not executed rather the alert in `else` is executed every time.

Comment: How are you calling open(), send(), onreadystatechange? SHow that

Answer (score 0):

First this is wrong

```
setTimeout(process(),1000);
```

You are going to be making an infinite loop, plus it makes no sense why you would do that. You are calling the function, not assigning a reference to it.

```
setTimeout(process,1000);
```

Second, readystate can be 0,1,2,3,4 and that is NOT an error as your alert states.

---

Change your code to be

```
function handleServerResponse () {
    if(xmlHttp.readyState==4 ){
        if( xmlHttp.status==200){
            var xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML;
            var xmlDocumentElement =xmlResponse.documentElement;
            var message=xml.DocumentElement.firstChild.data;
            document.getElementById("underinput").innerHTML=message;
            setTimeout(process,1000);
        }
        else{
            alert('something went wrong.\n' + xmlHttp.status + "\n" + xmlHttp.statusText);
        }
    }
}


function process(){
    var food=encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("userinput").value);
    xmlHttp = createXmlHttpRequestObject();
    xmlHttp.open("GET","foodstore.php?food="+food,true);
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=handleServerResponse;
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}
```

Comment: ready state change is not an error but i just printed a message to ensure that my if is not working.....

Comment: everytime i run a program it is printing alert in the else rather than goin to if statment

Comment: my code is showing normal output ,  it isnt showing updated ajax statement

Comment: hey if(xmlHttp.readyState==4 ) worked when i opened it normally rather dan on server bt now if( xmlHttp.status==200) is not working . xmlHttp.status is showing equal to 0

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout(process(),1000);
the usage of setTimeout is incorrect.
try setTimeout('process()',1000); or setTimeout(process,1000);